# Salvar atualização de uma variavel a cada execução

Tags: python, funções, while

Gostaria de saber como posso manter a alteração do valor de uma variavel dentro do while de forma global, pois cada vez que é executado o programa novamente ele volta e seta o file2 = "" e sempre vai entrar apenas no if e nunca no else

```
import testeDiversos as td
from emailOutlook import enviarEmail

file1 = [
    ['12345-189-abc-7810', '12345-189-abc-7810', 'ACKNOWLEDGED'], 
    ['12345-189-abc-7810', '12345-189-abc-7810', 'ACKNOWLEDGED'],
    ['12345-189-abc-7810', '12345-189-abc-7810', 'ACKNOWLEDGED'],      
    ['12345-189-abc-7810', '12345-189-abc-7810', 'ACKNOWLEDGED'], 
    ['12345-189-abc-7810', '12345-189-abc-7810', 'ACKNOWLEDGED'], 
    ['12345-189-abc-7810', '12345-189-abc-7810', 'ACKNOWLEDGED'],   
    ['12345-189-abc-7810', '12345-189-abc-7810', 'ACKNOWLEDGED'], 
    ['12345-189-abc-7810', '12345-189-abc-7810', 'ACKNOWLEDGED']
]

file2 = []


def consInfraction(file1, file2):
    inicio = True

    while (inicio == True):
        if (file1 != file2):
            print("arquivos diferentes")
            file2 = file1
            enviarEmail
        else:
            print("Estão iguais")
        break
    return


print(file2)
```

após execução o `file2` deveria ser igual ao `file1` até que o `file1` seja alterado, mas se executar novamente o código ele mesmo assim entra no `if`.

OBS: o ultimo print do código é impresso o valor, apenas quando encerra a exeução ele perde o valor.

Comment: retorno do print(file2)[
    ['12345-189-abc-7810', '12345-189-abc-7810', 'ACKNOWLEDGED'], 
    ['12345-189-abc-7810', '12345-189-abc-7810', 'ACKNOWLEDGED'],
    ['12345-189-abc-7810', '12345-189-abc-7810', 'ACKNOWLEDGED'],      
    ['12345-189-abc-7810', '12345-189-abc-7810', 'ACKNOWLEDGED'], 
    ['12345-189-abc-7810', '12345-189-abc-7810', 'ACKNOWLEDGED'], 
    ['12345-189-abc-7810', '12345-189-abc-7810', 'ACKNOWLEDGED'],   
    ['12345-189-abc-7810', '12345-189-abc-7810', 'ACKNOWLEDGED'], 
    ['12345-189-abc-7810', '12345-189-abc-7810', 'ACKNOWLEDGED']
]

Comment: mas ao executar novamente o código, ele entra apenas no if e nunca do else, onde na segunda execução ambas as variaveis devem ser identicas.

Comment: Esse código não faz nada, em momento algum a função `consInfraction()` é chamada e `file2` sempre vai ser uma lista vazia fazendo com que toda a premissa da pergunta seja falsa. Considere [edit] a pergunta e adicionar um [mcve] que funcione e que remova o código sobre enviar email que não está relacionado a questão.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Este é um dos paradigmas do Python, ***Python nao copia objetos passados durante a chamada de funcoes***, em outras palavras nunca será possível copiar um parametro de uma funcao ou mesmo atribuir o mesmo à uma variável global.

O que é possível, no entanto é alterar esse parametros.

Quando se trabalha com listas o método mais tradicional é o `.append`, entretanto este adiciona o objeto ou lista à lista de destino.

Caso voce chame dentro da sua funcao : `file2.append(file1)` adicionará os objetos do file 1 (uma lista) à sua lista file2, no entanto nao tera uma cópia e sim uma adicao da lista dentro da outra lista. (file1 será acrescentado ao file2) = `[file2 [[ file1 ]]]` (file 1 foi adicionado um nivel abaixo da lista file 2 - nested)

Mas entao, como fazer?

A solucao é `.extend` , voce extenderá a lista vazia com todos os valores da lista file1 e assim atingir o resultado esperado.

Substitua no seu código `file2=file1`, por `file2.extend(file1)`
quando a funca for re-executada ela retornará "Estao iguais"

[Veja aqui uma explicacao visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KH5jB.png)